# How to check requirements. txt file package are not used in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have a number of packages in the requirements.txt file. I need to list which packages are used in the Django project and Which packages are not used in the Django project using the command prompt. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it's not clear if you're looking for this, but from what I've gathered, I think you may find just what you want in this thread. [How to see unused dependencies in requirements.txt?](https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/eozdsf/how_to_see_unused_dependencies_in_requirementstxt/)

Comment: Yes. I need that. .but In single command use to see the unused dependencies in Django project. is it possible?

Comment: If you've used virtualenvironment, then you can simply just use `pip freeze` command while your virtual environment is activated and that will list out all the packages/libraries that have been used. also check out this package [pip-check-reqs](https://pypi.org/project/pip-check-reqs/) if you really want to list the packages that have NOT been used. but specefically to your question I don't think a single command gonna give you specifically what you're looking for.

Comment: Actually, my question is I have around 80 packages in the requirements.txt file. Some packages not used in my project. So, I need to list which packages are used in the project and which packages are not used in the project.

Example: If we give pip freeze in the command line. it gives what packages I installed it will show. I need a list

Comment: I understood your question. As I said in my previous comment I don't think a single command is gonna give what you're looking for. I believe you didn't check out the package [pip-check-reqs](https://pypi.org/project/pip-check-reqs/). In the description of the package, it says "you have a long-running project that has some packages in requirements.txt that are no longer actively used in the codebase. The pip-extra-reqs tool will find those modules so you can remove them"... which is what  you want. If you have no other option, you can give it a try.

Comment: pip-extra-reqs tool  How to use this tool

Comment: I haven't used it personally, you may go through its page for more info about it. Also, I just found PyCharm could be very helpful in this case of yours, and give you just what you want, go through this thread where they explain how to get unused packages from requirements.txt [JetBrains Thread](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/managing-dependencies.html), also check out [this StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62383040/7610724) thread for some more explanation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer for Jetbrains Thread

Answer (score 0):

If you used any virtual environment like VENV, PIPENV etc. You can run you virtual env and in command prompt , use this command:    `pip freeze  >> requirements.txt`

This will have all the  packages used in this project.